# False positive unit test result

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I have notice that unit testing in javascript and its frameworks is very painful. Many fail positive results. I.e

```
it('should call Event.create when all if ok', function () {
  EventsPersistancyService.accept(message).then(function () {
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(s3);
    done();
  });
});
```

EventsPersistancyService:

```
var EventsPersistancyService = {
  accept: function acceptService(msg) {

    var worker_id = WorkerCacheService.get('some login');
    var app_category = AppCategoryService.get('some');
    Event.create('msg'); <------------  **first**

    var p = Q.all([worker_id, app_category]).then(function () {
      var content = msg.content.toString();
      content = JSON.parse(content);

      var tmp = {};

      return Event.create('msg'); <------ **second**
    });

    return p;
  }
}
```

In that example test pass but it shouldn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not creating a MCVE?

Comment: Could you explain what MCVE is?

Comment: Look [here](http://goo.gl/yGJ9t6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you never defined the done callback in your callback to `it`. But for promises, it is better to return the promise in your test, mocha will wait for promises to resolve.

```
it('should call Event.create when all if ok', function () {
  return EventsPersistancyService.accept(message).then(function () {
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(s3);
  });
});
```

A working example with your done callback (note the `done` declaration as function argument):

```
it('should call Event.create when all if ok', function (done) {
  EventsPersistancyService.accept(message).then(function () {
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(s3);
    done();
  });
});
```